# Jetpack Compose Load URI Image on Screen

Tags: android, image, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I am trying to pass a data class which has URI profileImage value on it and I want to populate UI with that profileImage uri value.
when I try to "upload" from gallery and populate UI, it works as I wanted. But when I try to pass userDetails data class to my ProfileScreen composable, and get the profileImage value in a LaunchedEffect, it gives me the correct uri value, but for some reason Coil - AsyncImage is not populating the UI with that uri value.

1- I pass userDetail data class from HomeScreen to ProfileScreen

2- at the top of the composable code block, I do LaunchedEffect to update imageUri variable to hope that I populate the UI with userDetails?.profileImage?.toUri() value

3- when I try to upload an image by selecting from gallery, it works fine. I can populate UI like that.

All I want is to populate UI when user first enters the composable. LaunchedEffect is not working for some reason. And also, when I pick image from gallery, I get it's uri value. I tried copy pasting that uri to imageUri as "urivalue".toUri() it is not working too.

How can I solve this any ideas?

```
@Composable

 fun ProfileScreen(
     onSignOut: () -> Unit,
     viewModel: ProfileScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
     userDetails: UserModel? ) {
     

var imageUri by remember { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }

LaunchedEffect(true) {
    Log.i("MYTAG" , "IS EMPTY? ${userDetails?.profileImage?.toUri()}")
    imageUri = userDetails?.profileImage?.toUri()
}

val permissionLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia(),
    onResult = {
        imageUri = it
        Log.i("MYTAG", "it $it")
    }
)


Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    AsyncImage(
        model = imageUri ?: R.drawable.ic_user_place_holder, // Use a default image resource
        contentDescription = "",
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(4.dp)
            .size(150.dp)
            .clip(CircleShape),
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    )

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(12.dp))

    Button(onClick = {
        permissionLauncher.launch(
            PickVisualMediaRequest(
                ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly
            )
        )
    }) {
        Text(text = "Pick Image")
    }
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

    Button(onClick = onSignOut) {
        Text(text = "Sign out")
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `am trying to pass a data class which has URI profileImage` Do away with that class. Only pass the uri for a test. Dont make it complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ImageBuilder` instead of directly passing `imageUri` in `model` argument.

```
AsyncImage(
        model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
            .data(imageUri)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_user_place_holder)
            .build(),
       contentDescription = "",
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(4.dp)
            .size(150.dp)
            .clip(CircleShape),
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    )
```

And if this doesn't work then `imageUri` might be null when `image` is build. In that case, you can trigger something to do force recompose in order to build image again.